# jQueryUI DatePicker not closing in IE

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am using jquery ui-datepicker in my website. After selecting the Date calendar was not closing this issue only in IE browser but it works in other browsers.

I tried autoClose  and change event to close the calendar but it is not  working

```html
<input type="text" placeholder="mm/dd/yyyy" class="custom-input-text" id="datefiled">
```

```js
$("#enrich_end_date").datepicker({
  changeMonth: true,
  changeYear: true,
  autoclose: true
});
```

Comment: Which version of IE and jQuery are you using? Note that jQuery 2.x and newer do not support legacy versions of IE

Comment: IE-11 and tried with  jQuery v2.2.2 and  jQuery UI - v1.11.1

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/R9AT2/1/ please look at this link

Comment: @Parth Raval: This is Working as Expected, Need one suggestion on this example they are using Jquery  1.10.1,  I am using  Jquery  1.11.1. Can I replace the version

Comment: @PDSSandeep boss You can replace/update Jquery version if it works properly.